# Android Cursor database

Tags: android

```
CHandler handler=new CHandler(getApplicationContext());
Cursor C=handler.returnc(name);
if(C!=null)
{
    C.moveToPosition(1);
    String me="me";
    while(C.moveToNext())
    {

        String content=C.getString(0);
        String sender=C.getString(1);

        if(C.getString(1)==me)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sender, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        Handler query
        public Cursor returnc(String abc)
        {
            SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
            return db.query(TABLE_a, new String[]{KEY_CONTENT,KEY_FROM}, KEY_ac+"=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(abc) },null, null,null);
        }
```

The query at position 1 is returning me but then too the if condition in the grabber is not getting out to be true that is

```
if(sender=="me")
```

I am not getting the reason behind that what could be the reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C.getString(1)==me   should be C.getString(1).equals(me). You want to compare the values of the two strings, not that they are the same object, right?

Comment: Thanks alot :) i was preety much screwed with the problem